# Highcharts - areaspline with negative values, area should be always at the bottom

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to create a chart with Highcharts, with negative values, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vargapeti/LjL03o8h/3/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Area chart with negative values'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'value'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                stacked: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Area with negative values',
            data: [[0, -7.0], [1, 6.9], [1.5, 9.5], [3, -6]],
            fillColor : {
              linearGradient : [0, 0, 0, 300],
              stops : [
                  [ 0, Highcharts.Color('#FFA500').setOpacity(1).get('rgba') ],
                  [ 1, Highcharts.Color('#ffffff').setOpacity(0.3).get('rgba') ]
              ]
        }
        },
        {
            name: 'Area with positive values',
            data: [[0, 13.0], [1, 26.9], [1.5, 29.5], [3, 14]],
            fillColor : {
              linearGradient : [0, 0, 0, 300],
              stops : [
                  [ 0, Highcharts.Color('#d2d8df').setOpacity(1).get('rgba') ],
                  [ 1, Highcharts.Color('#ffffff').setOpacity(0.3).get('rgba') ]
              ]
        }
        }        

                ],

    });
});
```

I need however, the orange area to be always between the X-axis and the curve, regardless of the negative values. So basically I want to shift the curve "Area with positive values" under zero, but keep the filled up area under the curve.

Is it possible with Highcharts anyhow?

Thank you.

Comment: Something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/LjL03o8h/4/

Comment: Could you show kind of screenshot/mockup what is the expected result? I'm not sure if I understand you correctly.

Comment: I am not yet allowed to post pictures to stackowerflow. Please check following links.

I would like to get this: https://www.copy.com/s/wmEkaVeFdi2D/Area1.JPG instead of this: https://www.copy.com/s/X4jFJGEPL6Nd/Area2.JPG. 

As you can see, in the required diagram, the colored area is under the curve, regardless, where the 0 value on Y axis is.

Comment: The links above are not working with IE for some reason. Please try to open them with FF or Chrome

Comment: Try my answer - and just for future, better description means faster and more accurate answers ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your question.

To plot the values above zero, you can do something like this ,

```
        yAxis: {               
            min:0
        },
```

Check this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/LjL03o8h/5/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I need is, that (in my example) the orange area would be under, and only under the blue line. So the area between the blue line and X Axis would be completely orange, and there would be no orange area above the blue line, even if it is under zero.

Answer (score 2):

Simply set [`threshold: null`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.areaspline.threshold) for areaspline series. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/LjL03o8h/6/

```
plotOptions: {
    area: {
        threshold: null
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer helps me in a case of negative min y values in a polar area chart. Without setting threshold, there would be a blank shape at the center of the area.

Answer (score 0):

Just check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41107037/148271), it might help you. Also because you have negative an positives both in same series, you might want to check [this](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8517#issuecomment-399516509) and [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/13rxlqryn3).